# Show Instagram Search Popup

Tags: javascript, instagram

I need to click on instagram search input to display
one show the results popup, but neither attempt worked.

```
document.querySelector('[class=" QY4Ed P0xOK"] > input').click()
```

can anyone help me with this task?

[image: Instagram]

***I just need to trigger a mouse click, I don't need to type any text.***

Comment: each element in the search popup has a unique classname which changes every time you search so thats why your code wont work

Comment: Actually I just need to click and show the popup but that doesn't work

Comment: I tried simulating a mouse click using javascript but to no avail.

Comment: instead of click use `.focus()`

Comment: focus() didn't work I already tried, thanks!

Comment: Search for the listeners in that element and check what triggers the result popup.

Comment: @Emel Any help on how to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **$r** with the [react devtool extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)

[image]

trigger:

```
$r.setState({hasFocus:true})
```

Comment: I tried this way
document.querySelector('[class=" QY4Ed P0xOK"] > input').setState({hasFocus:true})

but i got a wrong command
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).setState is not a function at.

Comment: only try `$r.setState({hasFocus:true})`

Comment: is it possible to run without a react extension?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $r is not defined

Comment: it's not possible without react devtool. download : [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)